# JavaScript: Custom shaped button to play WAV

Tags: javascript, button, wav

I wish to make a webpage with 12 coloured circular buttons arranged in a circle, like the 12 points of a clock face, in the middle of the frame / browser window.

When each button is pressed it should play a WAV file. (It is to be a musical instrument, and these are Shepard Tones for the 12 pitch classes).

I wish to accomplish this using JavaScript, so that it works on all popular browsers: Safari, IE, Firefox, Chrome.

Specifically my question is: **how to create a coloured circular button at a specific location?**

π

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article describing how to place items on a circle using CSS. This will get you in the right direction, just use JavaScript to apply those specific styles instead of CSS: http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/04/02/items-on-circle/